Where to throw Errors on MVC Model: Service or Controller?
I'm creating an Backend with Express using the MVC Model, but I still don't know where to throw the errors.
I'm using the express-async-errors and the http-errors
, so I can throw the Error anywhere, that the Error will be handled by a middleware that I've created.
But my question is:
1 - I throw the complete Error on my Service like this:
export default class UserService {

  public error(){
    throw createError(404,"Error Message")
  }
}

and don't create try/catch blocks on my Controller
2 - I throw a simple Error or message on my Service and let the Controller deal with it:
Service
export default class UserService {

  public error(){
    throw Error("Error Message")
  }
}

Controller
export default class UserController {
 public simpleMethod(){
  try {
    userService.error()
  } catch (error:any) {
    throw createError(404,error.message)
  }

 }
}

3 - Or just return a value like and object with an property called error and let the Controller handle everything, like this:
Service
export default class UserService {

  public error(){
    return {error:"Error Message"}
  }
}

Controller
export default class UserController {
  public simpleMethod() {
    const message = userService.error()

    if (message.error) {
      throw createError(404, message.error)
    }
  }
}

Note: I was thinking the best way to handle this was directly on the Service, because you can be more specific on the type of error, but some people recommend to do this on Controller, so, what is the correct way to handle this?

In general, the service should be agnostic to where it is used, and it wouldn't know that it's used in a http endpoint or elsewhere. In practice, if you know you're implementing a http-only microservice, you may already give the controller a hint which status code to use in its response, to avoid needless duplication.

This question is about control flow and exception handling, it's not specific to the mentioned technologies, it should be addressed at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Where the error is throwed depends if it is a full HTTP APP or not.
1 - Full HTTP API/Server
If it is a API used only for HTTP Requests, you should throw the Errors on the Service Layer, just like the first example on my question, because:

You can throw more specific status and messages

Your Controller gets cleaner

The Controller don't need to always have a try/catch block to treat the Error

The Service errors are handled the same way all over your application

Let the Controller layer just handle the requisition/response, because that's what it's made for!


2 - Not a Full HTTP API/Server
If it is not only used for HTTP Requests, the best way is to throw the Error on the Service Layer only with the specific Error Code and message, and let the Controller handle the Error passed to it, and decided what status to give it and how to send it.
In this case it's the best option, because the Service can be used on other places of your App, not only the HTTP Controllers

More specific messages, yes. Error codes, also. But a http response status code should usually reside in the request/response layer that is the controller, so mix that only if a) your service is only used by http controllers or b) if the benefits from #2 and #3 are large enough to violate the SRP and introduce a slight code smell.

Yeah, in my case I'm only using the server for HTTP. So if you think you have a better response/example, give it as an answer please, I can remove my answer if I think it's better than mine.

This is something I have spent a lot of my time. I have tried and experimented a lot of different approaches and this is what works the best for me. I am sharing an example of tenant registration via email, so that you can plan it accordingly for your use case/APIs.
It might look intimidating at first as it requires so many steps to setup, but the best part is you have to do it only once. After that, you can just copy the paste the code files to different projects and they will work flawlessly as these code files will work independently.

Come up with a proper/fixed response structure irrespective of if it is an error or success response. For me it was

{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": {...}
}

success will be true or false based on the operation, message will be a proper message explaining the response/result and data will contain any kind of associated data payload with the response, if required.

Create a middleware function that will be able to process any error or any success object thrown/returned from the Controller (and yes, for me Controller is the best place as it holds the overall business logic) and will be able to send a proper response after processing it.

// put below code in a file named as response-handler.js

const { logError, logInfo } = require('../logger');
const { HttpError } = require('./error');

function sendSuccess(code, success, message, data) {
    return {
        code,
        success,
        message,
        data
    }
}

function sendError(code = 500, message = "something went wrong!") {
    throw new HttpError(code, false, message);
}

function handleResponse(result, req, res, next) {
    const { code, success, message, data } = result;
    
    if (code) {
        logInfo(`responded with ${code}: ${message}`)

        return res
        .status(code)
        .json({
            success,
            message,
            data
        })
    } else {
        logError(message);

        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'something went wrong'
        })
    }
   
}

module.exports = {
    handleResponse,
    sendSuccess,
    sendError
};

So through out my codebase, within the controllers, I will be using sendSuccess and sendError to return success or error object, that will be eventually processed by handleResponse to send a proper response.

Create a custom error class that will be used to throw errors. The native Error can handle only message. But we will required error/status code, success flag and message to properly send a response. Thus

// put the below code in error.js

class HttpError extends Error {
    constructor(code, success, message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
        this.success = success;
        this.name = this.constructor.name;
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    HttpError
}

The sendError in point 2 will eventually use HttpError to throw the errors.

Mount the handleResponse middleware in the app.js.

const authRoutes = require('./auth/route/auth.route');
const tenantRoutes = require('./tenant/route/tenant.route');
const expenseRoutes = require('./expense/route/expense.route');
const categoryRoutes = require('./category/route/category.route');
const { handleResponse } = require('./core/http/response-handler');

app.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'hello from euro!'
    });
})
app.use(authRoutes);
app.use(tenantRoutes);
app.use(expenseRoutes);
app.use(categoryRoutes);

app.use(handleResponse); // <- handleResponse must be the last middleware, this is important, so that it can handle all the routes defined above it


Configure the routes

// put below code in the route tenant.route.js

const router = require('express').Router();
const API_ENDPOINTS = require('../../support/request-mapper');
const { registerUserViaEmail } = require('../controller/tenant.controller');

router
    .post(
        API_ENDPOINTS.REGISTER_VIA_EMAIL,
        [],
        (req, res, next) => registerUserViaEmail(req,res).then(next).catch(next)
    )

module.exports = router;

registerUserViaEmail(req,res).then(next).catch(next) is the crux of this setup. In simple terms whatever good (then) or bad(catch) happens inside registerUserViaEmail, let handleResponse deal with it. You will understand this once I will show you the controller code.

At last here is the controller code

//put the below code in tenant.controller.js

const { passwordEncoder } = require('../../core/crypto/password');
const { sendSuccess, sendError } = require('../../core/http/response-handler');
const { logError } = require('../../core/logger');
const Tenant = require('../model/tenant');

async function registerUserViaEmail(req, res) {
    const tenant = await Tenant.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec();

    if (tenant) {
        sendError(409, "user already exists!");
    }

    try {
        await Tenant.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: await passwordEncoder(req.body.password),
            provider: 'BASIC'
        })
    } catch (error) {
        logError(error.message, error);
        sendError();
    }

    return sendSuccess(201, true, "user registered successfully!");
}

module.exports = {
    registerUserViaEmail
}

As you can see I am able to handle custom/handled errors(401 duplicate user error), unhandled errors (catch block error) and the success response.
So, once you setup the basic files, only the routes and controllers are going to change from project to project.
Hope this will help you to think about a framework that will work for you best.

The names sendSuccess and sendError are rather confusing, since neither of them send anything - they return an object or throw an exception.

You should use .then(…, …) instead of .then(…).catch(…)!

OP is already using http-errors, no need for defining HttpError yourself. Btw captureStackTrace should no longer be necessary with ES6 subclassing, and I would recommend to keep the message parameter first for Liskov substitution.

Treating normal responses as errors within the expressjs framework is weird. Not sure about performance implications, but I think this will come back to bite you later. Why not just use .then(handleResponse, handleError)?

I don't think this answers the actual question: should errors be thrown (or sendError be called) in the service or in the controller?

@BlackList96, thanks for the response, and I have no doubts it works for you, I gave you an upvote, but I don't think it's a good way to mantain it for a long time, with the specificity I want to create my project. What I mean is that, you're handling stuff that should be handled on a service directly in the controller, and is not dividing it very well, not using classes and creating functions that are already supplied by the packages I'm using.

@Bergi, you've created a comment saying that, in general, the service should be agnostic to where it is used, but the controller should have a hint of the status and error, can you give me an example as an answer?

@Kobra This is a very basic and example. Of course, I don't put everything inside controller. I use controller more like a manager who has all kinds of required providers, or more specifically services at its disposal.

@Bergi Thanks for your input. I am not a expert of JS so didn't know the concepts you explained. But will look forward to use them whenever needed.

@BlackList96, yes, but that still doesn't answer my question friend :/
